# How to launch a long-running Python code in a Docker container running on a remote server

Tags: server, ssh, python, docker

I connect via the [Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) to a Docker container running on a remote server. The Docker container is based on an Ubuntu image:

```bsh
...# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

I want to launch a long-running Python code in the Docker container. The Python code must continue to run, even after I close Visual Studio, and of course I want to be able to connect again to the shell where the code is running, at a later time. What tool can I use to do this? I can install Ubuntu packages in the Docker container.